# FusedLocationProviderClient getLastLocation/getCurrentLocation Returns null when app is paused Even After invoking requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

For my specific use case, I need to fetch the device's real-time location updates and pass them to a remote server at 15 15-second frequency(or less than 15 seconds). To achieve this, I wrote a foreground service that initializes a `FusedLocationProviderClient` with `interval` and `fastestIntetval` as 15s. I am using an external HandlerThread's looper to invoke `requestLocationUpdates`.

When the app is in the foreground, location updates are received in `onLocationResult` callback of `LocationCallback` and also if I invoke `getLastLocation()` then it returns the same location. But whenever the app is minimized (service still running, the foreground notification is there), `onLocationResult` does not gets triggered and invoking `getLastLocation()` returns null.

Is this expected behavior from Fused? If not, how can I fix this issue. I am sharing the codes bellow:

```
    private val mLocationRequest =
        LocationRequest().apply {
            interval = updateFrequency
            fastestInterval = updateFrequency
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }
    private val mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient by lazy {
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(
            this
        )
    }
    private val mLocationCallback: LocationCallback by lazy {
        object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
                super.onLocationResult(p0)
                p0?.lastLocation?.let {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - (Constants.lastLocationFetchTimestamp
                            ?: 0) > minTimeBlockThreshold && Constants.currentLocation != null
                    ) {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private lateinit var mServiceHandler: Handler

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        getLastLocation()
        val handlerThread = HandlerThread(LocationUpdatesService::class.java.simpleName)
        handlerThread.start()
        mServiceHandler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent): IBinder {
        super.onBind(p0)
        stopForeground(true)
        return mBinder
    }

    override fun onRebind(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onRebind(intent)
        stopForeground(true)
    }

    override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
        if (!mChangingConfiguration && preferenceManager.requestingLocationUpdates()) {
            startForeground(
                (applicationContext as ContractorApp).notificationIdForForegroundService,
                NotificationUtils.getForegroundServiceNotification(applicationContext)
            )
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mServiceHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }

    fun requestLocationUpdates() {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
            preferenceManager.setRequestingLocationUpdates(true)
            startService(Intent(applicationContext, LocationUpdatesService::class.java))
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                mLocationRequest,
                mLocationCallback, mServiceHandler.looper
            )
            startRecursiveForceLocationFetchCall()
            Constants.locationUpdatesRequested = true
        } catch (unlikely: SecurityException) {
            Utils.reportNonFatals(unlikely)
            preferenceManager.setRequestingLocationUpdates(false)
        }
    }

    fun removeLocationUpdates() {
        try {
            Constants.locationUpdatesRequested = false
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
            preferenceManager.setRequestingLocationUpdates(false)
            preferenceManager.remove(Constants.ACTIVE_VEHICLE_TYPE)
            stopRecursiveForceLocationFetchCall()
            stopSelf()
        } catch (unlikely: SecurityException) {
            Utils.reportNonFatals(unlikely)
            preferenceManager.setRequestingLocationUpdates(true)
        }
    }

    fun updateNotificationText() {
        (getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).notify(
            (applicationContext as ContractorApp).notificationIdForForegroundService,
            NotificationUtils.getForegroundServiceNotification(applicationContext)
        )
    }

    private fun getLastLocation() {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful && task.result != null) {
                        if (task.result != null) {
                            Constants.currentLocation = task.result
                        }
                    }
                }
        } catch (unlikely: SecurityException) {
            Utils.reportNonFatals(unlikely)
        }
    }

    private fun onNewLocation(location: Location) {
        // logic to send location to remote server
    }
    private var forcePing: Job? = null

    private fun startRecursiveForceLocationFetchCall() {
        if (forcePing == null) {
            forcePing = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
                while (true) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this@LocationUpdatesService,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                            if (location != null) {
                                // Use the last known location
                                val latitude = location.latitude
                                val longitude = location.longitude
                                onNewLocation(location)
                            } else {
                                Timber.tag("FORCE_PING").d("Last known location is null")
                            }
                        }.addOnFailureListener {
                            Utils.reportNonFatals(it)
                        }.addOnCanceledListener {
                            Timber.tag("FORCE_PING").d("Issue")
                        }
                    } else {
                        // No permission
                    }
                    delay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(15))
                }
            }
        } else {
            forcePing?.cancel()
            forcePing = null
            startRecursiveForceLocationFetchCall()
        }
    }

    private fun stopRecursiveForceLocationFetchCall() {
        if (forcePing != null) {
            forcePing?.cancel()
            forcePing = null
        }
    }
```

Comment: I solved this issue later by myself. This is a case of a foreground service being called from the background. Somehow, during the onUnbind phase when the service was being promoted to the foreground, it used to take some time (1-2.5 seconds), which is why it was requesting background location. Later, I changed the service to be promoted to the foreground whenever it starts and removed the process of stopping and starting it based on unBind, reBind, and unBind.